# Words for adding to beginning and end of list, and beginning and end of node

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

Say, I have a small list of numbers: [2,4]. (I'm using a bit of math/code notation, but the idea is the same)

If I were to add '0' to the beginning I would have [0,2,4]. I believe this is known as a **prepend**.

If I were to add '5' to the end I would have [0,2,4,5]. I believe this is known as an append (**postpend**?).

If I were to add '1' before '2' I would have [0,1,2,4]. I'm not so sure, but believe this might be a **prefix**.

If I were to add '3' after '2' I would have [0,1,2,3,4]. I'm not so sure, but believe this might be a suffix (**postfix**?).

Thoughts? Corrections?

Comment: "Postpend" is often used to mean appending to the rear vs front.  "Append" could arguably be used, but is ambiguous in some contexts.  Of course, "postpend" is not a "real" word, if that's of any concern to you.  For inserting values in the middle I'd use "insert before" or "insert after" -- any other term is apt to be ambiguous.

Comment: What is the question? Are you looking for terms to describe the insertion of 1 and 3, here? If so, there is no special term, besides *insert* (before or after).

Comment: Well, I was hoping to keep to the same sort of "theme", that is "pre/post" or something similar for both. Insert certainly works, but is more lengthy when specifying before or after. Not like that's any sort of real problem, more just me nitpicking.

Comment: This is what `car` and `cdr` are for.

Comment: FWIW: The C++ programming language includes a library of "containers", a "list" is one type of container, as is a "deque" (double-ended queue).  The terms used in C++ for the operations you describe are push_front, push_back, and insert.  Insertion is done before the element specified.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Those only work if you have a LISP.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Askers are expected to do some background research before posting a question, *and* show it. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the terms:

- prefix  (add at beginning – 'prepend')
- postfix (add at ending – 'append')
- infix   ('insert' in between)
- adfix   (hypernym for all above)

Note that the "xfix"s and the "xpend"s are independent sets. Both sets of terms exist and are used in different contexts, but never mixed.

HTH.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context differences? I've been reading through definitions since before I asked the question, and cannot seem to grasp the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that has some consistency with *prepend* and *postpend*, use

- **interpose**

http://i.word.com/idictionary/interpose

Answer (score -1):

The terms that come to mind here are ones often used in phonology: *word-initial* and *word-final*.

These are compact ways of saying

> At the beginning of the word...
>   At the end of the word...

So for these to be relevant to your situation, we can just change *word* to *list*. Now you can make sentences like these:

> Add a list-initial 0 and a list-final 5.

As for a term for the middle, you might say *list-middle*, but that sounds strange.

Also, the word for a "fix" in the middle of the word is *infix* and the word encompassing all "fixes" is *affix*.

Comment: "the word encompassing all "fixes" is affix." etc., -- source?

Comment: @Kris [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix)'s article on affixes

Comment: Please, always site the source.

Comment: @Kris I don't see sources in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mention using code notation, it's worth noting that in [programming lingo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Basic_concepts_and_nomenclature), what you have done is:

- added/inserted 'head' (first node)
- added/inserted 'tail' (last node)
- inserted before given node
- inserted after given node

[Wikipedia]